# Not able to install scrapy in my windows 10 x64 machine

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, pypi

I got `pip install scrapy` in cmd,

it said `Collecting scrapy` and after a few seconds I got the following error:

`Command "c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-2nfj5t60\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0bjk1w93-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2nfj5t60\Twisted\`

I am not able to get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pip3` insttead of `pip` since you are using `python3`

Comment: Didn't work for me. First it showed me that "Failed building wheel for twisted"  and then the same error occurred

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed the issue using this:

1. From the this link >https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted   downloading the twist version which is compatible with your OS and install it to your computer or virsualenv.
2. In command line: *pip install path-to-your-twist-file***.whl*
3. Then using *pip install scrapy*

Done!

Answer (score 0):

According to scrapy documentation it doesn't run on Python 3.5 on windows machine. Try using python 2.7 (perhaps in virtualenv) and see what happens.

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

Comment: Link you shared says that it works on Python 3.4 or above clearly